# Full Text Justification in newer SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way of justify a paragraph in SQL Server Reporting Services? Currently we can justify to left, right or center but I need full justification to a paragraph!

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no full justify option for text boxes, even in 'newer' versions of SSRS (I assume you mean 2012 onwards).

Your only option is to use a third party product such as [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfreportingservices/Justify+FullJustify+Text+Alignment)